# Should we make meta.superuser.com to point to this website

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

I think it would be useful if [meta.serverfault.com](http://meta.serverfault.com) ( and [meta.superuser.com](http://meta.superuser.com)) is pointing to this website. After all, there is no reason why we can't lump all the meta discussion together in a single website.

**Now [meta.serverfault.com](http://meta.serverfault.com) works<strike>, but [meta.superuser.com](http://meta.superuser.com) is still not working. SO Admin, please fix this.</strike>**

EDIT not by OP, July 29, 2010:
Both URLs now work, but not in the way originally suggested in this post.

Comment: @Nhu Soon Hui: please edit your question to remove the "status-completed" tag -- meta.superuser.com is still not working. thanks!

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com still not working

Comment: Why would it be useful?

Comment: @The Cat - Not sure, but if it works for SF, it should be for SU too, consistency and metaphysical considerations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to [a recent change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/superusercom/), the <strike>accepted</strike> — EDIT: now formerly accepted — answer is no longer correct.  [meta.superuser.com](http://meta.superuser.com) is now a standalone meta site just for SU, and [meta.serverfault.com](http://meta.serverfault.com) is now a standalone meta site just for SF.

Comment: So, I've changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

I've retagged this question with "bug" because it appears that https://meta.superuser.com/ is not working (https://meta.serverfault.com/ redirects properly though.)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another problem with not having a consistent, overarching brand for the trilogy...

Answer (score 2):

It should probably just be a 301 redirect.

Comment: Or a CNAME entry pointing here.

Answer (score 2):

For the <s>three</s> two users who will ever type meta.superuser.com in their browser (it certainly isn't linked that way anywhere that I know of), this now works.

Enjoy, all two of you!

Comment: You fixed the third "highest bug" in the list, I'm sure you can take the rest of the day off, now.

Comment: @Gnoupi, actually...it really wasn't a bug imo.  But it is good to see that stuff is being worked on anyway.

Comment: @jjnguy - it wasn't, but it was in the bug list. Hence it should be fixed. Don't question the community :] Joke aside, this request probably would have died somewhere unheard, if not for these "bugs" and "reqs" lists.

Comment: I want the logo to say Super User too :P

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe, it just gets tricky when you have to disambiguate serverfault meta questions with stackoverflow meta questions. But that said, there should be a high amount of colinearity, and tags should be able to supplement the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If that suggestion is implementented, each "question" will have to be tagged by the site name or site-agnostic tag. It would probably better if the engine made a choice mandatory. (ie. made the asker choose *at least one* site tag before the question is posted )